# How to remove string from array in multiply function

Tags: php

```
function multiply (...$nums ){
  $result = 1;
  foreach ($nums as $num ){
    if (gettype($num)==gettype("k")){
       continue;
     }
    echo $result = $result*$num;
  }

}
echo multiply(10, 20);
echo "<br>";
echo multiply("A", 10, 30);
echo "<br>";
echo multiply(100.5, 10, "B");
```

I tried to make a function to multiply the argument that is given to it, but if the argument is a string, it skips it, and if the argument is a float, it converts it to an int before starting the multiplication process

Comment: What problem are you having? You should probably add a space after echoing each result.

Comment: `multiply()` doesn't return anything, there's no point in echoing the return value.

Comment: Do you really need to echo each time through the loop? Maybe you should just do one `echo` after the loop is done. Or change it to `return $result` at the end, and use the caller's `echo`.

Comment: Where do you convert to `int` before multiplying?

Comment: That float to int thingy bugs me, too. I don't think the splat operator does this. Did you try `var_dump($num);` to see where the conversion happens?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
`is_string` you can use to check if it is a string and then if it is skip it.
`is_float` to check if it is float and if it is use `intval` to convert...

```
<?php

function multiply(...$arguments) {
    $result = 1;
    foreach ($arguments as $arg) {
        if (is_string($arg)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (is_float($arg)) {
            $arg = intval($arg);
        }
        $result *= $arg;
    }
    return $result;
}



echo multiply(10, 20, 'TEST'); //200
echo multiply("A", 10, 30); //300
echo multiply(100.5, 10, "B"); //1000
```

Comment: You could concatenate _PHP\_EOL_ instead of using `echo "<br />";` when applying this solution.

Comment: i do not really care about `<br />` i think that was in his code, but thanks 

Comment: Not you, I mean @QA, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter) to remove not-numeric values, [`array_map()`](https://php.net/array_map) to cast into integers, and then, [`array_product()`](https://php.net/array_product) to compute the product of these values.

Code ([demo](https://3v4l.org/MgJM2))

```
function multiply(...$nums): int|float 
{
    $nums = array_filter($nums, 'is_numeric');
    $nums = array_map('intval', $nums);
    return array_product($nums);
}

echo multiply(10, 20) . "\n";
echo multiply("A", 10, 30) . "\n";
echo multiply(100.5, 10, "B") . "\n";
```

Output:

```
200
300
1000
```

Comment: Also needs to convert float to int, in last test case should be 1000, but i like your style, just change that and it is better  

Comment: @SinisaM You're absolutely right! I've updated my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Ye better i love it 